# Can an employer ask a part time worker to come in 1 time a week on their day off for a 15 minute meeting?

Tags: management, united-states

My employer is asking for me to come in for a 15 minute staff meeting on my day off EVERY WEEK.  When I asked her if I couldn't just be told what was discussed on the days I work I was told no it would work better if we all were there. It's 15 minutes. What could we possibly have to discuss that would be so important for us all to be there.  My co worker has small children so my boss isn't asking her to come in on her days off because she would have to find daycare. While I understand, even though I don't have children is it fair to only ask me to give up my time off? for 15 minutes? It's not worth my time, can I ask to be paid for a full hour? My boss doesn't like me to schedule appointments on my days I work, because it takes up her time and I have days off to do that stuff.  So I schedule those things for my days off, and now she wants part of that time too.  do I have any legal rights?

Comment: Thank you she already knows I work on my days off at another job just wants me to come in to this meeting before I go to work at the other job. I'm in Iowa.

Comment: Can I ask to get paid for a full hour or only the 15 min

Comment: @JoeStrazzere Note that some states in the US have rules for minimum amount of time to be paid per day, such as one example here: https://www.nh.gov/labor/faq/wage-hour.htm#minimumhours So in NH if a worker has to come to work for a 15 minute meeting, they must be paid no less than for 2 hours of work. But this is obviously very locale-specific, I'm not aware of any federal law of this sort.

Comment: How much is your travel time to work? And can you ask to leave early on your working days to compensate for this 15 minutes meeting (plus travel may be)?

Comment: Your boss is a POS, and is aided in this by the laws of Iowa. In no other democratic country would this be tolerated.

Comment: What is meant to be "off" for a day you to to work, how is this off-day defined? Can you get another weekday off if this meeting is so important?

Comment: @DJClayworth ROCKS.  Quite true.

Comment: Workplace.SE should start a Political Action division where we take matters like this in to hand!   :O

Comment: Besides the restriction noted for NH, many states have laws about consecutive work days, i.e. hourly workers in some industries in NY cannot be required to work 7 consecutive days, they must have one 24 hour block of uninterrupted time off per week: https://davidrichlaw.com/can-i-make-my-companys-employees-work-seven-days-a-week-in-new-york/

Comment: Could you attend the meeting via telephone? Your boss can call you then use speakerphone. Most mobile phones have a speakerphone feature

Comment: Ha I cant believe that's even legal; perhaps you could do it remotely, or phone into the meeting so you don't have to be there? it isn't just "15minutes" when you take into account time to/from work and inconvenience.

Comment: And it's Christmas time !

Answer (score 13):

> is it fair to ask me to give up my time off

It is absolutely **NOT FAIR**.

> Is it legal?

Unfortunately, in the US, it is legal.

If you say you won't do such a thing, it's OK for the boss to let you go from the job.

If you lived in a country that cared about worker's rights, this would never happen to you.  (On the other hand, the US has lots of work and it's easy to get a job, and things are cheap, so, you have to take the good with the bad.)

> What should you do?

I absolutely encourage you to ***not do this***.

## Don't do it!

I hope you do not do it one more time.

Here is some language to tell your boss:

> Dear boss, as always thanks for this great job.  But I am not able to come to the 15 minute meetings on Mondays.  It's just not possible for me to spend that time on my off day.

Note that you don't have to explain yourself.  You don't have to explain "why" you can't spend the time!  Just state that it is "just not possible" for you.

It could be you have to get a new job.

**I am really certain you can get another job easily.**

You clearly have a good attitude, and you won't let people "walk over you". It's a certainty you'll get another job - a better one.

Regarding your boss, I hope they rot in hell.  Anyone who would do something like this to a hard-working employee, is a real ass.

Important: if boss offers to "pay you" for the meeting, I strongly suggest you say No.  It will be "some sort of scam" where they end up offering you "11 minutes" of pay or some such nonsense.  Don't fall for it!

Good luck in your new and better job!

Comment: This is the correct answer, insults and all.

Comment: A halfway point could be to do teleconferences. There is absolutely no need for physical presence if all they do is a daily standup.

Comment: You know, I think this is for a modestly paid position and not involving software, etc.  Secondly, I would never in a million years ask someone to "telecommute in" on their day off.  It's just as bad.  I want to get the boss in question and give him or her a good talking to about basic human manners - taking the facts as stated at face value, the situation is disgusting.

Comment: The only valid "teleconference" option would be if they record the meeting and the OP watches it when they have time (that is: the next time they are actually on the clock)

Comment: +1 for “rot in hell”. That said, I once drove about 400 miles to a one hour meeting and 400 miles back in the evening. Got paid for a day of work, and for driving expenses which were about three times as much and tax free. So I didn’t mind at all.

Comment: "...if boss offers to 'pay you' for the meeting..."  Well, if the boss _doesn't_ offer to pay for the meeting, then in fact it is _not_ legal.  Court cases have established this.  Here are examples of federal law requiring "waiting time" to be paid, and requiring that if meal time is unpaid, the employee's time must be his/her own.  If "waiting time" is on the clock, how much more would a company meeting be?  [Code of Federal Regulations](https://www.ecfr.gov/cgi-bin/retrieveECFR?gp=&SID=167842928accd251fbca30147f00a8cf&mc=true&r=PART&n=pt29.3.785#se29.3.785_115)

Comment: Wait, better yet, here's a section that specifically covers meetings.  [Lectures, Meetings, and Training Programs](https://www.ecfr.gov/cgi-bin/retrieveECFR?gp=&SID=167842928accd251fbca30147f00a8cf&mc=true&r=PART&n=pt29.3.785#sg29.3.785_126.sg5)  It gives four criteria for a meeting to be unpaid: (a) outside employee's regular working hours; (b) Attendance is voluntary; (c) meeting not related to employee's job; and (d) no productive work performed.  The meeting described would fail criteria (b) and (c) and thus must be paid.

Comment: @Kyralessa Probably fails (d) as well (no productive work performed).

Answer (score 8):

> Can an employer ask a part time worker to come in 1 time a week on their day off for a 15 minute meeting?

Yes they can.

> Options

If you NEED the job just do it and take what is given.

If you WANT the job do it, ask for compensation for the travel time and expense both ways in addition to the 15 minutes.

If it makes the job UNVIABLE for you, refuse and see what happens.

Answer (score 4):

Two excellent answers already, though I'd frame it differently. Thinking of it as a "day off" is what's leading your employer to believe they can ask something like this - it seems they have no respect for the time you're not working for them, which is sadly far too common.

Instead, you could think of the time you *are* working for them, in which case this would constitute a change to working hours. It would be reasonable for you to ask how you would be compensated for this - and I say "compensated" as it would involve more than the fifteen minutes.

None of that helps if you can't or don't want to do this - that just leaves you with telling them it's not possible and accepting that this might mean they look for someone else to fill your position.

There's a definite double standard in the way they expect you to avoid scheduling other appointments for work days, and if you decide to put your foot down and damn the consequences it wouldn't hurt to make this comparison to them.

Worst case : you've learned something valuable about your employer and manager.